# How do you accept answers?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Accepting answers, what’s it all about?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/accepting-answers-whats-it-all-about)
>   [Where is the FAQ?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33331/where-is-the-faq)

Somebody commented on one of my questions:

> You've asked many questions, you should go back and mark some of them as accepted. – davr 16 hours ago

But I don't know how.

Comment: In future questions about SU should go on meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: @John - http://meta.stackoverflow.com was set up specifically for asking question about the site. No need to ask there, though. There is already an extensive post about "accepting answers": http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/accepting-answers-whats-it-all-about

Comment: @Phoshi - true, but one must keep in mind, that if someone doesn't know how to accept questions, he also probably doesn't know about meta, which is in all probability, the least known of them all.

Comment: @Idigas, very true, which is why we should tell them :p

Answer (score 5):

Click on this :
[alt text http://sstatic.net/su/img/vote-accepted.png](http://sstatic.net/su/img/vote-accepted.png)
next to the answer you find most helpful

Answer (score 3):

Click on the (faded out) tick to the left side of the answer that you feel is the best.

Answer (score 0):

Do note that -- while appreciated -- you have no obligation to accept answers. If someone is being too pressing about this flag their comments.